# Bash printf prefix

Tags: linux, bash, printf

In Bash I can use `printf` to format a string output like this:- (Note how I've added a suffix of `W` to the string and that this is not included in the padding)

```
$ printf "Blah %11.1fW\n" 123 456 78965 5 56
Blah       123.0W
Blah       456.0W
Blah     78965.0W
Blah         5.0W
Blah        56.0W
```

If I want to prefix the string I could do this:-

```
$ printf "Blah £%11.1f\n" 123 456 78965 5 56
Blah £      123.0
Blah £      456.0
Blah £    78965.0
Blah £        5.0
Blah £       56.0
```

However note how this results in the padding being applied before the prefix.

How (if at all possible) would I use `printf` to prefix the value before padding so the output would be as follows:-

```
Blah      £ 123.0
Blah      £ 456.0
Blah    £ 78965.0
Blah        £ 5.0
Blah       £ 56.0
```

If not possible any Bash solution would be appropriate.

Comment: Are the accountants happy with this?  In my experience `printf` style rounding cause accountants to faint.

Comment: @cdarke lol. This is an example only. No accountants are involved !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
$ printf "Rate: %11s\n" $(printf "$%.1f " 12345 123)
Rate:    $12345.0
Rate:      $123.0
```

Just be sure the choose the correct `%11s` for your case.

---

It seems that you addressed that space problem yourself. For the sake of completeness, I will put that in here.

```
$ printf "Rate: %11s\n" $(printf "$%.1f " 12345 123) | sed 's/\$/\$ /g'
Rate:    $ 12345.0
Rate:      $ 123.0
```

---

Here's the solution given by @FatalError:

```
printf "Rate: %11b\n" $(printf '$\\0040%.1f ' 12345 123)
Rate:   $ 12345.0
Rate:     $ 123.0
```

Comment: Aha yes, the problem with this is when you introduce the space between the currency symbol and the data.

Comment: Piping output into `sed 's/\£/\£ /g'` may help me here.

Comment: Without `sed`, you could: `printf "Rate: %11b\n" $(printf '$\\0040%.1f ' 12345 123)`

Comment: @FatalError Thats an awesome solution!! :)

Comment: Eh, I don't  like to wordsplit `$()` output but works in a pinch especially with printf. If Bash had some sort of `zip` function I'd probably use it 10 times a day for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. You'd need something like `strfmon`. Workaround:

```
$ a=(123 456 78965 5 56)
$ printf 'blah %*s %.1f\n' {,,,,}{$((10 - ${#a[n]})),£,"${a[n++]}"}
blah      £ 123.0
blah      £ 456.0
blah    £ 78965.0
blah        £ 5.0
blah       £ 56.0
```

Answer (score 2):

While I love ormaaj's solution for keeping things in the shell, I don't like using subshells unless I really need them.  And a line with both a subshell AND a pipe just seems ... unnecessary.

```
$ printf "Rate: %11.1f\n" 123 | sed 's/  \([0-9]\)/$ \1/'
Rate:     $ 123.0
```